# PostgreSQL JSONB Array - Find if a key exists

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

The table `Product` has a jsonb column `attributes` in PostgreSQL 9.6 and contains the following entries for the `attributes` column.

**Record 1:**

```
[
  {    "KEY1": "VALUE1",    "KEY2": "VALUE2"  },
  {    "KEY1": "VALUE3",    "KEY3": "VALUE4"  },
]
```

**Record 2:**

```
[
  {    "KEY1": "VALUE1",    "KEY2": "VALUE2"  },
  {    "KEY3": "VALUE3",    "KEY4": "VALUE4"  },
]
```

How can we filter the records which contain the `KEY4` key?
The jsonb operators given [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) doesn't provide the details for jsonb arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For table like this:

```
create table test_table
(
  id serial not null,
  data jsonb
);
```

Using your data

```
SELECT id, arr_elem
FROM test_table AS tt, jsonb_array_elements(
    (
      SELECT data
      FROM test_table
      WHERE id = tt.id
    )
) AS arr_elem
WHERE arr_elem#>'{KEY4}' IS NOT NULL
```

You basically unpack the array and join it back with the source table.

Result:

> id , arr_elem
>
> 2 ,    {"KEY3": "VALUE3", "KEY4": "VALUE4"}

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6d431/3)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to substitute the correct table and column names, but this should do the trick:

`FROM your_table jsonb_array_elements(your_table.the_array_key->'your_column') AS something WHERE something->>'KEY4'::text != 'null'`

Hard to say for sure without knowing the table and column names. The bottom line is that you need to use `json_array_elements`.

Comment: Can you explain how `jsonb_array_elements` in the `where` condition?

Comment: Updated the answer. When you save the `jsonb` AS `something` you can get what you need from the array. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE

Comment: What is `the_array_key` here?

Comment: Whatever the array is stored in. For example, if you have a table called posts and a column called comments, then it's `jsonb_array_elements(posts.comments)`, but if your array is nested in a key then it's `jsonb_array_elements(posts.comments->'whatever_the_array_key_is_called')`

Comment: It is providing the syntax error. Can you update for your query in the answer?

Comment: Not without your entire SQL statement :)